# c# set datarow DateTime field basing on DB type

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, datetime, operators

I'm writing a program which can use a SQLite DB or a MySql DB alternatively. (Depending if more than one has to use it, net infrastructure, etc...)

I've written a generic DBType interface and two classes that implement it based on the DB type. There is a function `DataTable GetAllRows(tableName)` that, as you expect, simply retrieves all the rows of a table and fills a System.Data.DataTable.  For SQLite I've used the [SQLIte connector](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)
and for MySql I've used the [MySql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Now the problem is when I read rows with the specialized DataReader (supplied from the connectors) the DataTable sets the column types with the types returned from this connectors. SQLite connector uses `System.DateTime` for the DateTime fields, MySql uses `MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime`.

I've also implemented an entity-provider framework so I implicitly convert each retrieved DataRow into an Entity (on-demand) so the DateTime fields will become a DateTime field into the corresponding entity class.

For example, suppose that in the DB there is a table:

```
userTable: 
field "userName" as string,
field "date" as DateTime
```

with one row:

```
"asd" 2000/01/01
```

I call GetAllRows for this table, now I've a DataTable with 2 columns:
the first column is a string field, the second column is System.DateTime or MySqlDateTime depending on the type of the DB I'm using for this run.

The row will be converted into an entity

```
class userTableEntity
{
    string name;
    DateTime data;

    /* methods... */

    implicit operator userTableEntity(DataRow row);
}

userTableEntity u = datarow; //uses the implicit operator
```

If I want to turn back and convert the entity into a DataRow I've to use something like this:

```
MyDataRow[userFieldName] = entity.name;
MyDataRow[dataFieldName] = entity.data;
```

If I'm using SQLite there is no problem.  If I'm using MySql, the line `MyDataRow[dataFieldName] = entity.data` will throw a type exception because `MyDataRow[dataFieldName]` is of type `MySqlDateTime` but entity.data is a `System.DateTime`

Surely I can switch between SQLite/MySql before assigning the field but I've something like 75 tables with lots of DateTime field so I don't want to create a switch case (or a if) each time for obvious reasons.

I've tried making a MyDateTime class which performs an internal conversion with those operators:

```
implicit operator DateTime
implicit operator MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime
```

but those operators will never been called because the type of the expression `MyDataRow[dataFieldName]` is `object` and not `DateTime` or `MySqlDateTime`!  Neither I can write an implicit operator to object because MyDateTime class is subtype of object, so it's not permitted.

Note that `MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime` has some useful methods:

```
public static explicit operator DateTime(MySqlDateTime val);
public DateTime GetDateTime();
public DateTime Value { get; }
```

and a ctor:

```
public MySqlDateTime(DateTime dt);
```

How can I arrange the code to do something like `MyDataRow[dataFieldName] = entity.data` without exceptions?  I can change the type of entity.data but I don't want to do a switch case each time and I prefer to maintain the DataTable as it is read (no type changing in the columns).

Comment: Not the answer to your question but, do you want to do all this work as a learning exercise? When not, maybe you should have a look at NHibernate or the Entity Framework. (Object Relational Mapping Frameworks)

Comment: Because I didn't know it very well and from a brief overview it doesn't fit my needs..